# Source url prefix appended to destination url when using CloudFront and S3 AWS

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, redirection, amazon-s3

I am trying to redirect a url, example.io, to www.example.org/survey/imagine.

Currently, my S3 bucket handles redirection with the following redirection rules:

`<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>www.example.org</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>survey/imagine</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>www.example.org</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>survey/imagine</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>`

My issue is when I add any prefix to example.io, that prefix is appended to the url of the destination.

Examples:

`example.io/something` redirects to `www.example.org/survey/imaginesomething`

`example.io/blah` redirects to `www.example.org/survey/imagineblah`

`example.io/blah/there` redirects to `www.example.org/survey/imagineblah/there`

Desired Result:

`example.io/something` redirects to `www.example.org/survey/imagine`

`example.io/blah` redirects to `www.example.org/survey/imagine`

`example.io/blah/there` redirects to `www.example.org/survey/imagine`

I am using CloudFront to handle the DNS services and distribution of example.io. In CloudFront for example.io, I have an invalidation with the object path `/*`. I have a behavior with path pattern `/*`, which should redirect all requests for `example.io/*`, where `*` is a wildcard, to the example.io s3 bucket endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

`<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>` removes the matched key prefix and prepends the new value to the path, after the leading slash.

Since you aren't specifying a key prefix to match, it replaces the "first zero bytes" with the specified string.

If you want to redirect to `/survey/imagine` no matter what path is specified, change this to `<ReplaceKeyWith>survey/imagine</ReplaceKeyWith>` which replaces everything, discarding the original path.